# Valid XML for posting to QuickBooks Online Edition - Receiving (400) Bad Request Error

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to post the below xml to https://apps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway and all I keep getting is the error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  See below for the C# code that I am using to post the xml.

Thanks,
-Jeff

UPDATE: To add more to my question, I am thinking that the (400) Bad Request error is indicating that I have something grossly wrong with the xml or with the way I am posting the xml.  So that is why I am asking this question... what am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
<SignonMsgsRq>
<SignonDesktopRq>
<ClientDateTime>7/20/2009 12:36PM</ClientDateTime>
<ApplicationLogin>APP_LOGIN</ApplicationLogin>
<ConnectionTicket>CONNECTION_TICKET</ConnectionTicket>
<Language>English</Language>
<AppID>APP_ID</AppID>
<AppVer>1</AppVer>
</SignonDesktopRq>
</SignonMsgsRq>
<QBXMLMsgsRq>
<CustomerQueryRq requestID="2" />
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>



WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
WebRequestObject.Method = "POST";
WebRequestObject.ContentType = "application/x-qbxml";
WebRequestObject.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
string post = XmlText.Text;

WebRequestObject.ContentLength = post.Length;

swr = new StreamWriter(WebRequestObject.GetRequestStream());
swr.Write(post);
swr.Close();

WebResponseObject = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Keith Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26133/keith-palmer) [mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154880/valid-xml-for-posting-to-quickbooks-online-edition-receiving-400-bad-request/1158910#1158910) the version number needs to be 6.0 but also need to include the onError attribute of the QBXMLMsgsRq tag. (I also corrected the time format too as recommend by [Keith Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26133/keith-palmer).)

Complete/working xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<?qbxml version="6.0"?> 
<QBXML> 
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq> 
            <ClientDateTime>2009-07-21T10:10:00</ClientDateTime> 
            <ApplicationLogin>APPLICATION_LOGIN</ApplicationLogin>
            <ConnectionTicket>CONNECTION_TICKET</ConnectionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language> 
            <AppID>APP_ID</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer> 
        </SignonDesktopRq> 
    </SignonMsgsRq> 
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError"> 
        <CustomerQueryRq requestID="2" /> 
    </QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your qbXML version to 6.0, QuickBooks Online Edition doesn't support 7.0 yet.

Comment: The version number was part of the problem but also needed to include  onError="continueOnError" in the QBXMLMsgsRq tag otherwise it would error out too.  I am putting the full XML that worked in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

where is the xml posted in request?? Or you are missing to paste some code here. I don't see the request has XML in the above code. The request is bad because the request contain no XML. At least from what I see above

Comment: Hi RJ, This line: string post = XmlText.Text; reads the xml from a textbox.  The above xml is in that textbox.
-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You can get the XML for a customer query at this site:

[QuickBooks Online OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)

Select CustomerQuery as the message. Use Chrome because it doesn't work in all browsers. Click XmlOps and you'll see the XML.

On another note, I have a commercial solution available here:

[QuickBooks Online C# Development Integration](http://www.jmawebtechstore.com/p/15/nopcommerce-quickbooks-online-connex)