# QuickBooks export feature in web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, quickbooks

I have to use  in my web application But i dont have any knowledge of this. Please help me regarding this . or give me suitable link which also tells basic of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a similar sort of problem like your problem on this post 
this question is one of the frequently asked on quickbooks with asp.net

please follow this thread

[Connecting an ASP.NET application to QuickBooks Online Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093030/connecting-an-asp-net-application-to-quickbooks-online-edition)

Comment: Thanks Steave i am looking to wards it.