# I am getting a 400 error when using QuickBooks API

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am going off the accepted answer from this post: [Connecting an ASP.NET application to QuickBooks Online Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093030/connecting-an-asp-net-application-to-quickbooks-online-edition)

I am getting a 400 error when making the connection thru C#. I have read that this might be because of an XML error. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2013-04-12T15:54:18</ClientDateTime>
            <ApplicationLogin>MY APP LOGIN</ApplicationLogin>
            <ConnectionTicket>MY CONNECTION TICKET</ConnectionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>MY APP ID</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonDesktopRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I am not seeing any issues with the XML. Yes I am substituting my actual applicationLogin,ConnectionTicket, and AppID. Am I missing something?

Comment: This might be related to your XML. However, it might not. Therefore, can you post the code that you use to submit this XML?

Comment: Post the full HTTP response you got back.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I didn't have the application setup correctly in the QB portal. I recreated it with the correct settings and that took care of my problem.